# extract common element from XML Schema element(xsd)

Tags: xml, xsd

i have this schema:

```
<xs:element name="element1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="found" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="element2">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="found" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

how can I extract common part from element1 and element2. Should I use group?

Answer (score 0):

You define a common type as below (NOTE: Haven't validated but you get the idea)

```
<xs:complexType name="stringWithAttribute">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="found" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

and specify this as the type of element1 and element2 as below

```
<xs:element name="element1" type="stringWithAttribute">
<xs:element name="element2" type="stringWithAttribute">
```